# how does input parameter of subprocess.check_output works?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to figure out how to use subprocess.
I want to sub-run a program, and get its output, within a main program using some data from the main program.
I know subprocessing is not the optimal solution but separating both programs is mendatory for this project.

So I tried a realy simple trial with 2 files :
the main one, named test_p1.py:

```
import subprocess
output  = subprocess.check_output('test_p2.py',shell=True,text=True,input='4') 
#I need shell=True for my project
print(output)
```

the second one, named test_p2 :

```
import sys
print(sys.stdin.read())
```

When I run this I expected to get my input back, but it is not working (nothing is printed).
I did a previous test where the second file is a simple print of a str, unrelated to sys.stdin and it worked fine.

So I guess the problem is either with the input or with sys.stdin.read()
Please help me :)

Edit:
I tried to convert test_p2.py to an executable as suggested but it did not work.

Edit 2 :
I also tried to use subprocess.run() instead of subprocess.checkoutput() in test_p1.py and to replace sys.stdin.read() by input() in test_p2.py.

This is test_p1.py

```
import subprocess
output  = subprocess.run('test_p2.py',shell=True,check=True,input='please help\n',encoding="utf-8",text=True).stdout
print(output)
```

and this is test_p2.py

```
a=input()
print(a)
print('input worked')
```

but nothing is printed when I subprocess part 2 within part 1.
I don't understand How I can simply send info to a file I subprocess.

Comment: This seems like it would fail, unless `test_p2.py` is both (a) executable and (b) in your `$PATH`. E.g., if I run it, I get `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'test_p2.py' returned non-zero exit status 127.`. If I change it to `subprocess.check_output('python test_p2.py', ...)`, it works as expected.

Comment: test_p2.py is an executable (I think) and in the same path as test_p1.py  I don't have the subprocess.CalledProcessError. I used to have it but after upgrading the subprocess module to its latest version I didn't need to raise this error anymore. I changed the first argument of subprocess.check_output to 'python test_p2.py' but nothing changed.

Comment: I would assume that `test_p2.py` is a python file not an executable, right?

Comment: I Converted test_p2.py to a executable, but nothing changed, it seems that nothing is sent into the stdin...

Comment: This worked fine once I added a valid shebang to `test_p2.py` and marked it executable. It also needs to be on your `PATH`. Alternatively, explicitly run `python test_p2.py`. Demo: https://ideone.com/c8oVet